# How to copy files from a remote server to hdfs location

Tags: shell, unix, hadoop, hdfs, sftp

I want to copy files from a remote server using sftp to an hdfs location directly without copying the files to local. The hdfs location is a secured cluster. Please suggest if this is feasible and how to proceed in that case.
Also I would want to know if there is any other way to connect and copy apart from sftp.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most convenient way (given that your remote machine is able to connect to the hadoop cluster) is to make that remote machine act as an HDFS client. Just ssh to that machine, install the hadoop distribution, configure it properly, then run:

```
hadoop fs -put /local/path /hdfs/path
```

Comment: The remote server belongs to a different vendor and installation of hadoop distribution doesn't seems feasible. Could you suggest any other workaround?Is copying to local the only option?

Comment: In order to get those files to HDFS you need to make them available to some HDFS client (some machine where you can run `hadoop fs -put...`).  To achieve this on that particular machine, it should be fine put all the hadoop stuff in your home directory and run from there, if you don't have root access. There's no daemon to run, you just need those jars, config files and scripts to be on the local file system.